# typescript: Derive types from Conditional Types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, string, types

Typescript supports [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).
But when I try to set value of `op` as string, it gives me error, how do I check the type and assign value?

```js
export const t = <IsMulti extends boolean = false>(): void => {
    const value = 'test';
    type S = string;
    type D = IsMulti extends true ? S[] : S;
    const op: D = value;
    console.log(op);
};
```

Error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'D'.`

I have even tried adding a parameter of same type `IsMulti` and adding check based on it

```js
export const t = <IsMulti extends boolean = false>(isMulti: IsMulti): void => {
    const value = 'test';
    type S = string;
    type D = IsMulti extends true ? S[] : S;
    if (!isMulti) {
        const op: D = value;
        console.log(op);
    }
};
```

still it gives the same error.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluation of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which depend on as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters is generally *deferred* by the compiler; if the compiler doesn't know exactly what `IsMulti` is, then it does not know exactly what `IsMulti extends true ? S[] : S` is, and so it won't let you assign a value of type (say) `S` to that conditional type, because it is unable to verify that this is a type-safe operation.  The compiler doesn't even really try to evaluate such conditional types; it leaves them as opaque things that almost nothing can be assigned to.

For your first example this is the desired behavior from the compiler; it really isn't safe to assign a `string` to `op` because `D` may well be `string[]`.  Nothing stops someone from calling `t<true>()`.  Just because `IsMulti` has a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `false` doesn't mean it *is* `false`.

---

For your second example, this is currently a limitation of TypeScript.  The compiler cannot use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow type parameters.  And therefore it cannot verify assignability to a See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for details.

When you check `if (!isMulti)`, the compiler narrows the type of the `isMulti` inside the subsequent code block from the `IsMulti` type to just `false`:

```
export const t = <IsMulti extends boolean = false>(isMulti: IsMulti): void => {
  if (!isMulti) {
    // isMulti is now known to be false 
    const fls: false = isMulti; // okay
    const tru: true = isMulti; // error
  }
};
```

But it does *not* narrow the type parameter `IsMulti` itself.  In general this is also desired behavior from the compiler, since `IsMulti extends boolean` implies that `IsMulti` might actually be the full [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `boolean` (as opposed to just `true` or just `false`) and so checking a value of type `IsMulti` would not be useful to narrow `IsMulti` itself.  All you could say with `if (!isMulti)` is that `IsMulti` could not be just `true`... but it might still be `boolean`.  Of course if it is `boolean`, then `D`, a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) would become the union `S[] | S`, and you should be allowed to assign a `string` to that.  So there's no plausible way that assigning `"test"` to `op` should be unsafe.

And yet, the compiler is unable to verify this.  It stubbornly leaves `IsMulti` alone, and won't let you assign anything to `D` because it defers evaluation.  It would be nice if there were some supported way to narrow type parameters, or to verify assignability to generic conditional types.  For now, there really isn't.  The above linked GitHub issue is a feature request to improve this, and there are a bunch of related requests that might help (e.g., [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) could restrict `IsMulti` to be exactly `true` or exactly `false`, and presumably then `if (!isMulti)` would narrow the previously generic type `IsMulti` to the specific type `false`, and `D` would be evaluated eagerly).  You could go to these issues and give them a , but it's not obvious that anything is going to happen here anytime soon.

---

Instead, in situations like this where you know more about the types than the compiler does, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress assignability errors:

```
export const t = <IsMulti extends boolean = false>(isMulti: IsMulti): void => {
  const value = 'test';
  type S = string;
  type D = IsMulti extends true ? S[] : S;
  if (!isMulti) {
    const op = value as D; // okay
    console.log(op);
  }
};
```

By writing `value as D` you're telling the compiler that you know that `value` is definitely of type `D`, even though the compiler cannot.  This allows the program to compile without error.  Note that this is not magic, and by doing a type assertion you are taking some of the responsibility for type safety away from the compiler.  If you have made a mistake or lied to the compiler, it can't always catch it:

```
if (!isMulti) {
  const op = ["oopsie"] as D; // still okay
  console.log(op);
}
```

So be careful!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AHA-WrC1aInYlnYRIAIjYYFQFGAkdSHIC3OxeIJIa6gpqdQamQlLSAA)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation.