# Conditional type not narrowed in false branch

Tags: typescript

Let's say I need a type that gets me the value of a certain property of `Obj`. The only issue, there are, as often in life, special cases. So I have the following code:

```
interface Obj {
  foo: number;
}

// Ignore the actual type of special case, it's only for
// demonstrative purposes.
type SpecialCase = { id: number };
type ObjKey = keyof Obj | "specialCase";

// This is the desired type I need:
type ObjVal<Key extends ObjKey> = Key extends "foo" ? Obj[Key] : SpecialCase;
```

That works pretty well. The compiler uses `Key extends "foo"` to tell that `"foo"` is an actual property of `Obj`, and lets me index it. But sadly, `Obj` has quite a few more keys that just `"foo"`. So the obvious next action is to reverse the condition. But for some reason, TypeScript isn't able to narrow the false branch of the expression:

```
interface Obj {
  foo1: number;
  foo2?: number;
  bar1: string;
  bar2?: string;
}

type SpecialCase = { id: number };
type ObjKey = keyof Obj | "specialCase";

type ObjVal<Key extends ObjKey> = Key extends "specialCase" ? SpecialCase : Obj[Key];
// Error: Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Obj'.(2536)
```

*[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IEYAuZEAVwFt1oBuAo0gJgH4raHnX0cKJWQBnMFFABzFoUFQuVcZJAy8AXzx4wATwAOKAMoGEwOABsAwnFEoAvLmTAAJj3qMoydS10G0WAGkIHWQHAGtg4hh-bAAfZAAiURMzKxsIBJZtfRQMTAA1CwAeIJCIAA9IEGdRGNKAPlDkUuQKqprE5IhTC2tbBOROZGNu1L6UKjyAbVKAXSYgA)*

I've (quickly) read [the chapter about conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), but haven't found any useful information.

This behaviour seems strange to me. The only reason I can think of why TypeScript would be doing this, is if `Key` is "more" than just `ObjKey`. But as far as I know, the constraint on the generic, `Key extends ObjKey`, only allows variants of `ObjKey`.

I've searched online for this a bit, but I seem to lack the adequate search terms, and couldn't find it. Pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue I think is in `ObjVal<Key extends ObjKey>`. Since `Key extends ObjKey`, it could potentially also have additional keys along with `ObjKey`. In the first part of the condition, we are explicitly checking for a type and all other **potential** additional keys go to the else part and hence TS is complaining.

Comment: @vighnesh153 That's what I addressed at the bottom of the question. As far as I know (and according to my tests), TypeScript only allows variants. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZGAe2IEYAuZEAVwFt1oBuAo0gJgH4raHnX0cKJWQBnMFFABzFoUFQuVcZJAy8AXzx4wATwAOKAMoGEwOABsAwnFEoAvLmTAAJj3qMoydS10G0WAGkIHWQHAGtg4hh-bAAfZAAiURMzKxsIBJZtfRQAWWIoexigkPiEugKMrN8UDEwANQsAHhLkCAAPSBBnUWLggD5Q5FaOrp7E5IhTC2tbBOROZGMp1NmUKjqAbRKAXSzzCDBkADcLDaxG8yb8wv6mIA). `More` is not assignable to `ObjKey`.

Comment: @​Elias - Very interesting question. I suspect @vighnesh153 is in the right ballpark and that it relates to the *general* case of `extends` rather than specifically to how it applies to string literal types, but I can't give a firm foundation for that. In any case, `type ObjVal<Key extends ObjKey> = Key extends keyof Obj ? Obj[Key] : SpecialCase;` is clearer (to me) so I'd use that. Still, would like to know what type argument we could give `ObjKey` that would not `extends "specialCase"` but would also not be `keyof Obj`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have thought about something in the ballpark of that (or the answer of vighnesh153), but as you stated in another comment, feels a bit like a "workaround". Normally, TypeScript is quite good at using literals as "individual types". So I would expect this to work.

Comment: @Elias - To me, it's not a workaround, it's just how I would write it. But I really want to know why your version doesn't work. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I personally would expect this to work (especially because in the real code there are multiple special cases to choose from :D [the workaround still works, just not as clean]). You wouldn't know of any GitHub issues about this, would you?

Comment: @Elias - You seem to be getting the impression I disagree. I don't, I'd also expect it to work, but I've been bitten by `extends` enough to suspect edge cases. :-) No, I'm not aware of existing issues on this (but I'm a weak reed re TypeScript issues). I suspect jcalz or captain-yossarian from Ukraine or Titian Cernicova-Dragomir will explain it in due course.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018294/typescript-derive-types-from-conditional-types) answer is related. Control flow analysis does not work on type parameters.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine as far as my humble understanding goes, I thought control flow analysis is happening in actual code. So, for example, `if (typeof x === "string")`.  My understanding is, that this is purely related to types, and not "control flow of the program". If this assumption is incorrect, this might be related to a previous question I've asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/73855505/10315665.

Comment: @Elias you are right CFA for runtime values and not for type scope. This is exactly I wanted to say, that we should not expect CFA inside conditional types. I think because `subtyping` is a complex topic, TS don't even try to infer `false` branch and- expects you to provide another one type conditional statement

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - So fundamentally, the type parameter isn't narrowed at all in the "false" part of the conditional operation? Just the "true" part? [This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAPAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAbgF8SAoUSKAIQWRA232PKpujoHtgALRnAA+9TuGgANAIwAeACpQIKYBAIATTPT78AfI0XLVGrXAD8UeQG0ARChsBdKBms2Qj8bUkAmBUpVqmtoC+oiGASb0UBau7k4utvYOVEA) supports that (it's basically a restatement of the question above).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder These are just my thoughts (revers engineering ), I did not find appropriate issue.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine `This is exactly I wanted to say, that we should not expect CFA inside conditional types. I think because subtyping is a complex topic` - I'm sure that this is a complex topic, but as you can see, at least I, did actually *expect* this to work. Further, I would consider this a (**somewhat** important) feature. JavaScript is a very dynamic language, which unfortunately requires a tool like TypeScript to have a very dynamic and robust type system. Do you think it's worth opening a GitHub issue about it? And thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Elias yes, I think it is a good idea to create an issue. The worst thing can happen - issue will be marked as a duplicate. Then, you can link this issue to the question. At least we will find a reason and official explanation

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51040, if anyone has something to add or correct me, please leve a comment

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone finds this in the future: This is in fact a missing feature and, as far as I know, not planned by the TypeScript team.

I have asked the following GitHub issue: [#51040](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51040), which was marked as a duplicate of [#48710](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48710). That issue, as of right now, doesn't have a lot of attention, so I don't think this will be going anywhere soon. But it is tagged as "awaiting more feedback", so if you have some, you now know where to put it :).