# Adding optional attribute to complex typed object, results in wrong inference

Tags: typescript, types, inference

I am struggling with a typescript error, which is not being able to be resolved in my editor, nor in the Typescript playground. Hence I am writing this issue here.

Please just have a look at the [Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgRQFdgBnGBCJAdQRgAsBlAGwQBM0AeAaTlFSVYk4ZKMgDmcALzCYopGIB8cAN4BYAFBw4MAJ5hgALjgAiEi3ZRjAbg1bWOpJgC2CbADk+RUuUoB+IwAUAG6YTMRGSIROAEZoAJRSSlw26gC+GhqgkLCIKGhYuATEZBTUtHQAwnQQrsDcvCD8gjJyEtIi4kpqmtp6hibY1bXWtnCYSCQA7mgkRh3yANoAuil2Ds6uHo1eJX6BIWH982IJkkkp6eqZ4NDwuvpF3qUcozx8wAJCx1It4gA0oyUklGAB9HrsyvRmGxOFwFKDwT5IZUhrhuPCruosrdeg8KpR0AgxC8evg3o0Ps1jgDSQ0mkJlHAFgBrYA6XIELhLIw7JFwVI0rRAlSjLQAegAVBLRVoJXAKqFsIQmJg+ehCEhsGroNo6HgSIQoEE2QA6OA0JhMOCxODYUJMYCsMboVBQXg4OhjCbTKAmmVwCVimV2phKlWoAJakBGbpaLTjKYzIzIdBoBiG406ACC3pmHHwClW-LiRiCNSdYIAClAIC4SHUy2xCxkeuKpf65QAVPVwACOxSRJD9rdlQZH-aelFmBCLqRS12y8HVmr52CgwFVwHxSEJxNGZLplK+sn+o07h8+KiZrPZyE53MRpX5grgCkjBKJRm3u-zXD+cE7BQEljOAxTFc08AAK0IMg4FYCA4CQCB6HEOBJnKXUEBIf8UKELC4Gg2D0B1e5ULAQ1IHrIdRnXGBDSQW0PwkTAhG-Ilf3-QCLhbSVpU0OUAEkdzQVD6Dwe48AgdBdX1DM2S9RMoCEYi3UwYR9GwBBCWwRidyJQ1VVKYcAzgAARYAsGVGA5hPeRbDlaELAiKJYigeyx2xHIJNyVMoHTI02RzRSSHzYV8AvZoACVgGwaBWA4alH0oDEtF8OBK0wWAEFCDgQK0Fl5LvG8pIIB98AKnQlgioReVKGgoXMNAZTSyIYiakcbNaWcUrgCJgGNKB5yxG4cliiY7hrbBWSQaJMEIH41w3VA2LEAIQJDMNNzWhSfSEVJgJlMCALofCSGqZUnRtNTWtcuAAhYuASoAAxTNM5OzXMlKeuJ-1iO0YLwQ7wKe3snAAeXQSKIFrEgnsQIQ1MctA+wHUp-3GJ0zogC64Fo+ixkQlz2rjRBpPuz6h1BiGoZhhIxpICAHRNJgIFWhNdpNKnIehpwhDlABGAAGOJRgFUYJwhac8rgmswAqYAEBYeQpf9XF+mMQYalwYwXxJ9mkyZYwdFIHWTCQ4wll1uN7EcFx3E8VHKCMfW3TOO6XakSRpCNk24DS4wuZp3njF6kxJntEhjB+mUxfHcHuZhmNVYkoxTEaywrdjrRY-2lIgA).

This problem is, that I am not able to add the `dynamicNextQuestion` attribute (ex. line 190) to any of my configurations, or otherwise I am not able to get the properly typed attributes in the  `calculate` function (line 173).

When I am removing the `dynamicNextQuestion` key from my configuration object, I am able to get the correctly typed `answers` object back.

Code:

```js
export interface QuestionWithSlider<K extends string = string> {
  type: "slider";
  dynamicNextQuestion?: (value: number) => K;
}

export interface QuestionWithChoice<K extends string = string> {
  type: "choice";
  answers: string[];
  dynamicNextQuestion?: (value: string) => K;
}

export type Question<
  K extends string = string,
  > =
  | QuestionWithSlider<K>
  | QuestionWithChoice<K>

export type Config<
  QK extends string,
  Q extends { [key in QK]: Question },
  > = {
    /**
     * Calculation function for the survey. Will be called after each answer.
     */
    calculate(ctx: {
    answers: inferSurveyAnswers<Q>;
  }): void | Promise<void>;

    /**
     * The questions.
     */
    questions: Q;
  };

export function createConfig<
  QK extends string,
  T extends { [key in QK]: Question },
  >(config: Config<QK, T>) {
  // We just do nothing with this, this is just for typing purposes.
  return config as Config<QK, T>;
}

/**
 * Infering the type of the survey answers for a specific configuration.
 * Default: string
 * Slider: number
 */
export type inferSurveyAnswers<Q> = Q extends Record<string, Question>
  ? Partial<{
    [key in keyof Q]: Q[key] extends QuestionWithSlider
    ? number
    : string;
  }>
  : never;

export const trockenbau = createConfig({
  calculate({ answers }) {
    // This should be a number (as of `inferSurveyAnswers`), because 
    // `qmOfRooms` is a Slider question, and should return a number
    if (answers.qmOfRooms) console.log(answers.qmOfRooms * 10)
  },
  questions: {
    dropCeilings: {
      type: "choice",
      answers: ["yes", "no"],
      dynamicNextQuestion: answer => (answer === "yes" ? "qmOfRooms" : "walls"),
    },
    qmOfRooms: {
      type: "slider",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @T.J.Crowder – added the (slimmed down to the core) example to the question and updated the link.

Comment: I can't spend more time on it to get to the root cause, but if you add a type annotation on `answer` in the `dynamicNextQuestion` function in `dropCeilings`, it fixes the problem: https://tsplay.dev/WzeErm (Not a reason to stop looking for the actual problem...)

Comment: It's [this surprising behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48710), more in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73932262/conditional-type-not-narrowed-in-false-branch).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by helping the compiler to make the right inference :

```
const dropCeilings: QuestionWithChoice
  type: "choice",
  answers: ["yes", "no"],
  dynamicNextQuestion: answer => (answer === "yes" ? "qmOfRooms" : "walls"),
}

const qmOfRooms: QuestionWithSlider = {
  type: "slider",
};

export const trockenbau = createConfig({
  calculate({ answers }) {
    // This should be a number (as of `inferSurveyAnswers`), because 
    // `qmOfRooms` is a Slider question, and should return a number
    if (answers.qmOfRooms) console.log(answers.qmOfRooms * 10)
  },
  questions: {
    dropCeilings,
    qmOfRooms
  },
});
```

By giving a type to your each of your questions, we don't have a problem anymore.